# FLutter : cant complete retrieving data from firestore

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-futurebuilder

i try to passing query from first page to second page within constructor

```
 Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ListWisataScreen(querySnapshot: dataService.getAllWisata(),)))
```

the query passed successfully and the data is showed up but is just half of them and the other data get following eror

```
Bad state: field does not exist within the DocumentSnapshotPlatform
```

here is the error [screenshoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jlpzN.png)

here is secondpage code

```
FutureBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
        future: querySnapshot,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if(!snapshot.hasData || snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(strokeWidth: 3,),);
          } else if(snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done && snapshot.hasData){
            return ListView.builder(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                itemCount: snapshot.data.docs.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  var doc = snapshot.data.docs[index];
                  return ListTile(...);
                }
            );
          } else if(snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.none) {
            return Text("Tidak Ada Data");
          } else {
            return Text("Cek Koneksi Internet");
          }
        }
    )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error is in your own data in Firestore...

Look again at your 5th document, you will see it is missing a field or a field is not properly filled-in... Most likely a typo..